# Data dimensional model

Tags: date, dimension, fact-table

I am trying to create dimensional model for creating RDBMS. I have to create  multiple fact tables. My question is regarding time fact table. I am using date as a fact table. Can I use time as fact table that will be related to date dimension. My purpose is to find sales yearly monthly.

I am trying to create dimensional model for creating RDBMS. I have to create  multiple fact tables. My question is regarding time fact table. I am using date as a fact table. Can I use time as fact table that will be related to date dimension. My purpose is to find sales yearly monthly.

I started with one fact table. I need to add measures for this fact table.I am trying to create dimensional model for creating RDBMS. I have to create  multiple fact tables. My question is regarding time fact table. I am using date as a fact table. Can I use time as fact table that will be related to date dimension. My purpose is to find sales yearly monthly.

Comment: You’re question is very confusing (to me). Why/how are you using date as a fact table? Your question contains a lot of statements that seem to be unrelated - or at least don’t follow a logical sequence to either explain your current design or what your challenge is. Can you update your question to try and explain either your design or your challenge more clearly?